# How to get SCons Install to behave the same way as build at different hierarchy levels?

Tags: scons

My project is the following tree

```
|-- A
|   `-- SConscript
|-- B
|   `-- SConscript
`-- SConstruct
```

and I want to install **A**'s content into `/install/A`, and **B**'s into `/install/B`, I achieve this by two similar looking SConscripts called from the top SConstruct. SConstruct sets up `env['INSTALL_DIR'] = '/install'` and exports it. 
The **A** SConscript looks like this:

```
Import('env')
env = env.Clone(
    INSTALL_DIR = os.path.join(env['INSTALL_DIR'], "A"))
env.Alias('install', env['INSTALL_DIR'])

build_result_obj = Program(...)
env.Install(env['INSTALL_DIR'], build_result_obj)
```

and similar for **B**.

When both, **A** and **B** are outdated, and I am in **A** subdirectory, I can run `scons -u` there, and it will only build **A**. But if I run `scons -u install` there, then it would try to install **B** as well, causing it to build **B** too.

I could resolve it by having different Alias names for install (`install-A`, `install-B`) and a combined one for two, but I don't want to remember all such names. I just want the install to behave the same as build with respect to the current location. How to achieve that?

Comment: Hmm, nobody ever had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add your install targets to the Default target list. There is a method env.Default() for this, please check the docs of SCons. Note, how you can add Aliases to the Default list, too (once defined they're pretty much treated like file targets).

Another thing to regard here is, that you shouldn't define the install Aliases as simply

```
Alias('name', path_to_folder)
```

Like in every other build system, SCons will regard your install folder as up to date, as soon as it exists...and then no updates of your to-be-installed files happen.
Instead, define the Alias *after* you called the Install builder, and add the return value...which represents the path to the "program" node:

```
build_result_obj = Program(...)
instobj = env.Install(env['INSTALL_DIR'], build_result_obj)
env.Alias('install', instobj)
```

Comment: Hmm, this does not sound right. I was planning to add 'install' as a default target so that my build installs by default (I won't need to type scons -u install). I've just tried it, and it does not have anything to do with the problem I describe.

Comment: In addition, I don't see any problem with my Alias definition. It works as expected and updates the folder every time. I understand this works when the source file changes and build_result_obj is updated. But it also works when I delete some of the installed files. I've tried your suggestion, and it works the same. But the problem stays as it was.

Comment: Oh, I think my install set-up works, because the directory timestamp changes when files inside are removed. And when some source is updated, build_result_obj is updated, so this too triggers the install. By the way, I took the install implementation from the examples in manual.

Comment: If you want to add the target named "install" (an Alias in your case) as Default, you first have to define the target such that SCons knows which actual files are meant when you say "scons install". Can you please give the URL to the place in the manuals that you're referring to?

Comment: Install reference: http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-install