# SCons Install ignores Default specification within script

Tags: python, installation, scons

This is related to [scons - always install after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24189440/scons-always-install-after-build)

With scons 2.3.2, I am trying to get SCons to install the target that gets built into its pre-defined location without running extra commands. The solution proposed in the link above does not work for me. So I am trying to use default targets instead.
Let's say my source is in `src/a` and I install into `/dst-path/a`. In `src/a` SConscript (called from the parent SConscript) I have:

```
result = env.MyBuild(some_tgt, some_src)
env.Install('/dst-path/a', result)
```

If I type `scons -u` in `src/a`, it builds but does not install. If I type `scons -u /dst-path/a` in the same location, it builds and installs. I can add `env.Alias('install', '/dst-path/a')` and then `scons -u install` would install. This much is described in user guide. But I want to run just `scons -u` to build AND install.

So my idea is to add `/dst-path/a` to default targets and only in place that could generate content for that location. So, in that SConscript in `src/a`,  I do

```
env.Default('/dst-path/a')
from SCons.Script import DEFAULT_TARGETS, BUILD_TARGETS
print "DEFAULT_TARGETS in %s is %s" % (env['MY_SOURCE_DIR'], map(str, DEFAULT_TARGETS))
print "  BUILD_TARGETS in %s is %s" % (env['MY_SOURCE_DIR'], map(str, BUILD_TARGETS))
# env['MY_SOURCE_DIR'] tracks current source path and evaluates to 'src/a' in this case
```

Presumably, this is equivalent to me calling `scons -u /dst-path/a` Now I delete `/dst-path/a`, run `scons -u` while in `src/a` and see

```
DEFAULT_TARGETS in src is []
BUILD_TARGETS in src is []
DEFAULT_TARGETS in src/a is ['/dst-path/a']
BUILD_TARGETS in src/a is ['/dst-path/a']
```

- yet nothing happens!. But if I run `scons -u /dst-path/a`, I see

```
DEFAULT_TARGETS in src is []
BUILD_TARGETS in src is ['/dst-path/a']
DEFAULT_TARGETS in src/a is ['/dst-path/a']
BUILD_TARGETS in src/a is ['/dst-path/a']
```

- and now it builds and installs, just as before. My code had no effect.

1. So why does it completely ignore my Default specification, even though it even makes it into the BUILD_TARGETS? Is it a bug?
2. How on earth can I coerce SCons to install the things it builds in one step?

BTW, not sure if it matters much, but I also use VariantDir to separate intermediate files from the source ones.

Comment: Does SCons do the right thing for you, when calling it from the top-level folder of your build? Can we possibly get rid of all the `-u` stuff while discussing the question? If yes, please edit your question accordingly. It looks as if this question is also related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560291/how-to-get-scons-install-to-behave-the-same-way-as-build-at-different-hierarchy .

Comment: Yes, related - I am taking another stab at it. I do need the ability to build (and install) a subtree, so I need to use -u, -U, or -D. I post one tentative answer here, but it's not satisfactory to me yet.

Comment: What happens if you change to :  install_nodes =  env.Install('/dst-path/a', result).  env.Default(install_nodes)

Comment: If I do that, I get all the install node names in DEFAULT and BUILD TARGETS, but nothing gets built (with `scons -U`) (scons: *** No targets specified and no Default() targets found.  Stop.) This is likely because of the same problem - I am building in a subtree, but install is outside.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've learned that "-u" affects things. It does not build any Default targets, according to the option help (I think --ignore_defaults option would be a better approach, but oh well...)

So, for SCons to not ignore the Defaults, one should use "-D" or "-U". "-D" picks up the defaults all over the build tree, regardless the current location - that's not what I want. "-U", however, honors the defaults as set according to the current location.

Now **the real problem turned out to be the install path!** I've tried changing the install location from `/dst-path/a` to `install/a` (i.e. within the build tree) and now, magically, everything works! That is even "-u" works as expected (without extra Defaults set), installing the file, when it is not there. And if I set the install path as Default, then "-U" works instead. But with `/dst-path/a` path, the "-U" says it found no Default targets. If I change nothing but switch the path, then it suddenly finds them and builds.

Basically, this would all work fine from the start had I had install path within the tree. But why would I want to install within the source subtree? This is a crazy limitation. I'd call this a bug.

So this solution only works if you install within the tree, and it works as expected, without any trickery. This still does not answer how to install outside the tree.

...And it does not. You must call the install target/path explicitly in the scons command. Some examples are:

```
scons -u /dst-path/a  # as seen in manual and FAQ
scons -u src/a        # if you have Alias('src/a', '/dst-path/a')
                      # but "scons -u" or "scons -u '.'" from src/a won't work!
```

Another way to put it: when it comes to external paths, the behavior differs. SCons won't build anything outside top path no matter what you do in Install, Alias, or Default, until that outside path (or its alias) is passed as a target to the scons command. And this has nothing to do with -u/-U, etc.

Comment: FYI: The difference between -u and -U is explained in the manpage.  "-U

    Works exactly the same way as the -u option except for the way default targets are handled. When this option is used and no targets are specified on the command line, all default targets that are defined in the SConscript(s) in the current directory are built, regardless of what directory the resultant targets end up in."

Comment: For an answer to your outstanding question you might want to have a look at #2 of the "most frequently asked FAQs" in our [FAQ list](http://scons.org/faq.html), right at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the FAQ pointer! And the install question is so popular for a good reason - the implementation is counter-intuitive, IMO. The result entirely depends on location. The FAQ doesn't add anything new, though. Examples with `scons {some-absolute-path}` are in the manual already. And Alias and Default examples use a sub-directory. My experiments show that **the only way of installing outside the top path is to have the install path as an explicit argument in scons command**, whether done literally, through Alias or through Default. So the answer to my question appears to be _"Impossible"_

Comment: When I run scons without arguments, I see that it knows the path it is building (`scons: building associated VariantDir targets: src/a`). However that does not match any of the *_TARGETS variables content. I traced this message to `variant_dir_target_climb` in Node.FS. If I can get SCons to think that "src/a" was passed as argument in the command, then I can get around my issue by using aliases. But I can't find how SCons obtains that "src/a", so I don't know how to  spoon-feed it to SCons. Changing COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS has no effect.

Comment: I have to apologize. Looks like my build got into some inconsistent state. After I ran scons -uc, things changed, and using external path stopped being a problem. Which renders this whole question misleading. I will delete it in a week, if there's no other feedback here. Meanwhile, I have managed to find a solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560291/how-to-get-scons-install-to-behave-the-same-way-as-build-at-different-hierarchy, which I will post over there later